# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString if statement?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, uiwebview

In Xcode, I'm trying to get my UIWebview to run this:

```
 function setSizeValue() {
   for (var i=0; i
     if(document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].options[i].text == 8) {
       document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].selectedIndex = i;
       }
    }
```

How would I put this code in a NSString properly so the function could work and could be called under

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:codeAbove];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code has syntax errors, if you fix that, just change " charcters with \".

Comment: could you please demonstrate how I would be able to add a JavaScript if statement and function similar to mine but without the errors to the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString string